# NSManagedObjectContext does not saved when the App Quits & Relaunches

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I could not find why the core data NSManagedObjectContext not get saved when my app quits and re-launch. Every time when i quit the app and re-lanch, database is empty

**AppDelegate**

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
[[ShowScreenManager sharedInstance] reset];

// Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
[self saveContext];
[self.tracker set:kGAISessionControl value:@"end"];
```

}

```
- (void)saveContext
{
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}


}
```

**Save to core data**

```
// get manageObjectContext
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
fetchRequest = nil;

if(fetchedObjects.count == 0){
    // insert
    anItem = [NSEntityDescription
                   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SomeName"
                   inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
else{
    // update
    anItem = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}

aSequnce.all = strSequnce;


// save context
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

}
```

Comment: How are you terminating the app?  Unless you disable background mode, that delegate method will never be called.

Comment: Just quit the app from xcode or quit the running app on the device

Comment: Why are you removing the code from your questions? This invalidates the answer provided.

Comment: @adiga there are some method/object names i cannot let visible

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1):

`applicationWillTerminate:` is basically never used in version of iOS after 4 (when background running came in). You should not rely on it for anything.

You should generally be saving the context after updates rather than waiting for app termination.

You can move your logic to `applicationDidEnterBackground:` but this still won't be called if your app crashes or is terminated from Xcode.